# Both sharepoint server and sharepoint foundation run in same machine?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

Does it work if both sharepoint foundation and sharepoint server installed in a single machine?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Have you thought of using Virtual Machines (such as Hyper-V or VirtualBox) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the way you tagged your question, the answer is that it depends.

If you are talking about the same SharePoint version (Foundation 2010 and Server 2010 for example), then just install Server and you'll have everything that Foundation offers as well because SharePoint Server includes SharePoint Foundation.  SharePoint Server just adds more services on top of what Foundation provides. There is no need to install both.

If you are talking about having Foundation 2007 and Server 2010, for example, where there are fundamentally different versions of SharePoint being installed, then no, install these on different servers as different Farms.